# Why is my float returning zero and repeats with UIStepper?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I'm multiplying price by the quantity chosen vai a UIStepper.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
- (void) stepperForQuantity:(UIStepper *)sender
{
    double value = [sender value];

    //NSLog(@"%d",(int)value);

    NSLog(@"%.2f",selectedPrice);

    self.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)value];

    int total = [self.priceForPopUp intValue];

    selectedPrice = value * total;

    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.2f", @"$" ,selectedPrice];

    NSLog(@"%.2f",selectedPrice);

}
```

I `NSLog` the `selectedPrice` and this is what I get when I click the plus icon on the UIStepper:

In this case the start price of the product is 35.00.

```
 35.00
 0.00
 70.00
 70.00
 105.00
 105.00
 140.00
```

Also now I've noticed there are repetitions of the number as seen above. I can't have this as this would be a huge issue for ecommerce.

Here is my UIStepper

```
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 75, 0, 0)];
        stepper.minimumValue = 1;
        stepper.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperForQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [view addSubview:stepper];
```

Passing to next view

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@",segue.identifier);
    PaymentViewController *transferToPayment = segue.destinationViewController;




    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"homeToPayment"]) {
       // NSLog(@"test home payment");

        transferToPayment.price = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",selectedPrice];
        NSLog(@"Price passed %.2f",selectedPrice);

    }
}
```

Comment: Code where you populate your stepper?

Comment: Ill show you the UIStepper.

Comment: i noticed that if i click the + to go to say 70.00 then click next to go to a different view, and come back to the UIStepper and leave it at 35.00, it still nslogs 70.00 so maybe its not resetting?

Comment: also if i just run the application, and leave it at 35.00 which is the start price, it nslogs as 0.00 when i segue to the next view, using prepareForSegue.

Comment: What output do you see if you log `value`?

Comment: i get 2,3,4..etc. for every + clicked

Comment: so right now i have two issues, one is that if i dont click plus at all, and i hit next to go to a different view, it shows up as 0.00, the second issue is that if i click it a couple times and for ex. i times it by 12. so that 420.00 and if i click next, its fine but when i go back to the previous view and not click + then it will proceed as if its still 420.00

Comment: You need to show more code - how are you passing the data to the next view. Also consider using NSDecimalNumber rather than floats for money values

Comment: You shouldn't pass strings when you can pass a number. Only convert to string when you have to (such as when you need to display). I suggest you set some breakpoint  sand use the debugger to work out what is going on

Comment: Are the repeats because you have logged it twice within the same statement? You logged `selectedPrice` twice within the same statement

Comment: ^^^^ I'm an idiot @farhan don't listen to me ha i get it now

Comment: hahaha yeah i realized i put it twice.  but that only fixed the repeats. i still have the issue of not resetting to the initial number and also being zero if not changed

Answer (score 0):

You should be responding to `UIControlEventValueChanged` events, not `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.